Use an external system-installed Scala library in Python in Databricks notebook
In the context of fixing an imbalanced dataset in pyspark, I found the following external library in scala which is similar to SMOTE for imbalanced data:
I installed it on my system with > $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages mjuez:approx-smote:1.1.2
but I don't know how to call it and use in my databricks notebook in python as I'm working in with pyspark:
import org.apache.spark.ml.instance.ASMOTE

// read dataset
val ds = session.read
                .format("libsvm")
                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                .load("binary.libsvm")

// using ASMOTE
val asmote = new ASMOTE().setK(5)
                         .setPercOver(100)
                         .setSeed(46)
val newDF = asmote.transform(ds) // oversampled DataFrame

